# Como fazer o this se referir a um item HTML que chama uma função quando clicado?

Tags: javascript

Estive lendo vários materiais a respeito do uso do `this` e seu funcionamento no JavaScript. Vi boas explicações sobre o contexto global, bind, apply e call, mas, ainda assim, não consigo entender como fazer com que ele (o `this`) passe a se referir a um item da página que, quando clicado, chama uma função (no exemplo abaixo, uma âncora HTML).

A propósito, também já fiz testes usando o `event.target`, mas sem sucesso.

Qualquer elucidação será muito bem-vinda.

```
<a class="link" href="javascript:chamaFuncao(p1,p2)">Texto 1</a></li>
<a class="link" href="javascript:chamaFuncao(p1,p2)">Texto 2</a></li>

function chamaFuncao(a,b) {
  (...)
  var texto = this.innerText // Aqui, o this sempre retorna a janela.
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Acabei percebendo que a solução é, ao invés de chamar a função por meio do `href`, chamá-la no `onclick`. Assim, o `this` aponta para a própria âncora, e não mais para a janela.

Comment: Se tiver uma situação em que precise usar no href, em vez do this você passa um ID na chamada (que inclusive não precisa ser do próprio elemento, pode referenciar qualquer outro). Exemplo: `<a id="batata" href="javascript:myfunc('batata');">` e recupera o ID no corpo da função. - De qualquer forma, trabalhar com eventos como `onclick` é o normal numa situação dessas (e nada impede de passar um parâmetro em vez de usar o this neste caso também, se for um elemento diferente do que faz a chamada), comentei só como complemento mesmo.

Comment: Concordo completamente, @Bacco. Inclusive foi isso mesmo que fiz antes de perceber que o problema estava no uso do href. Coloquei IDs como parâmetros e as chamei no corpo da função, exatamente desse jeito que você mencionou e funcionou também. No final das contas, foi mais um aprendizado. E muito obrigado por se dispor a compartilhar conhecimento e pela dica no geral.